# Terraform template_file non root command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I use a template_file in terraform script for run commands, in my script i need to start a postgresql instance, but when i execute the command i have this error:

```
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
```

my config file is this:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
 - systemctl start postgresql
```

aws cloud-config by default start provisioning using a root user, 
How can i run a command with non root users?

I think if i use a remot-exec this work, but i can't create a key pair created for use ssh.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your cloud-init script? If so where does the postgres install come from? Is it baked into an AMI? And if so why is the service not just enabled directly? And what does your systemd unit file look like for postgres?

Comment: postgresql already installed in ami.

Comment: Okay so why is the service not just enabled so you don't need to start it manually?